# Transition between two html pages

Tags: web, transition, portfolio

I found a great page transitions:

http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

I know these transitions could be silly for web experience, but i think they could really improve a mobile experience.
So i'm making a responsive personal web page and want to add some transition's like these to my mobile experience.

I download the files and saw that transitions are only possible between layers, so on the same html file. But i want to make these transitions between HTML pages, for example on my portfolio i have a portfolio page and couple of subpages of works.

If there is a better or easier solution with jQuery or something else, please advice, i would appreciate every comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These sort of transition effects, that use javascript (usually jQuery) require the info to be in the same HTML, as it's only going to be loaded once.

This doesn't mean you can't do it, it's just easier and faster with everything in the same page. Why would you want to keep separate files, anyway? Unless there is a requirement to do so (server requirement, pages actually living in different places), you'll gain more if you keep everything in one file.

You just need to organize your code well enough so it doesn't get confused.

For what you need, I think you'll probably find a **Parallax** effect much more useful. You can see [a lot of examples in this article](http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/18-beautiful-examples-of-parallax-scrolling-in-web-design).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

I didn't even thought to have all the content on the same page. I was just coding the site like usually in separated HTML pages.

Yea i know, the code should be organized that's the point. 

Thanks for the link and i will give it a shot and try to put everything in the same site, will see what happens :D

Comment: i think i will still need to do this with seperated HTML pages. The thing is it would be too much. I have 6 subpages and 20 subpages on portfoli. That means that the code in one HTML file would be over 10.000 lines...